# Typecasting in Python to Integer

Tags: python, string, integer, typecasting-operator

```
L = int(input())  
N = int(input())  
W, H = int(input().split(" "))  
for num in range(N):    
    if (W < L or H < L):    
        print("UPLOAD other")][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgtoS.jpg
[image]

Comment: Please add _text_ of your traceback, not images.

Comment: guys the code is in complete u can look at the complete code + error by clicking on the above code which pops up a image

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ there was a problem adding few code part so i embeded the image

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ anyway i got ur point , thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast a list of 2 numbers to int. [int only takes a number or a string as its argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

What you want is to [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) the int function to each item in the list.

```
>>> w, h = map(int, input().split(" "))
5 10
>>> w
5
>>> h
10
```

Comment: This is preferable to a list/generator expression: It's debatable, but for applying a built-in function to a list `map()` is cleaner. That being said, both will work. Also, `split()` should be equivalent or better than `split(" ")` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`int(...)` constructs an integer which cannot be unpacked to a tuple `W, H`. What you probably want is

```
W, H = (int(x) for x in input().split(" "))
```